# Factory reset on htc one mini 2 doesn't work

Tags: factory-reset

I'm trying to do a factory reset on my **HTC one mini 2** following the instructions on HTCs website here:
http://www.htc.com/uk/support/htc-one-mini-2/howto/511217.html

I can't access settings (it dumps me out to the home screen, hence the need for a reset), so I'm trying the hardware buttons method.

I hold **volume-down**, then hold the power button as per the instructions. After about 7 seconds, a black message box pops up saying "to restart your phone, press and hold the **volume-up** and power buttons". 
If I keep holding volume-down and power the screen then goes dark. Nothing else happens.
If when the message appears I let go, the message disapears, and my phone just returns to the locked screen, I can unlock it as usual.

I'm completely flummoxed, any ideas what to do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, so I figured it out (much googling, some trial and error, more than a few swearwords).

The htc guide (and most others on the interwebs that have just copied and pasted HTC's instructions) neglect to tell you that **the phone needs to be switched off**.

So, factory reset instructions for htc one mini 2.

1. press and hold power button and chose "power off"
2. press and hold volume down and power button
3. hold those for quite a long time
4. You should then end up in the "three android symbols menu" Let go of all the buttons
5. Press volume down until "factory reset" is selected, tap the power button.
6. Cross your fingers.